# Collapse Bootstrap and SimpleBar js not working together

Tags: bootstrap-4, scrollbar

I have issue with simplebar.js ( https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar/ ) and bootstrap collapse element.
Custom scroll doesn't show up (but it is initialized) but default scroll does.

With default scroll (click Item1 and Item2):

```
<div class="container" style="height:300px; overflow:auto;">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#item-1">Item 1</a>
    <div id="item-1" class="collapse">
      <ul class="nav flex-column ml-3">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Sub 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sub 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sub 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link"  data-toggle="collapse" href="#item-2">Item 2</a>
    <div id="item-2" class="collapse">
      <ul class="nav flex-column ml-3">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Sub 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sub 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sub 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 3</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Item 4</a>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r9en2d16/

With simplebar.js:

https://jsfiddle.net/ops71v3f/

Comment: Simplebar seems to be working in your second fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for answering but it was some time ago and css and js is linking to @latest so maybe developer did fix it.